# Again, a regex issue

Tags: regex

I'm spamming the forum full of questions about Regex, but I really need your help.

I have the following file:

```
<!-- Defines the template for the tabs. -->
<div class="tabs">
    <ul role="tablist">
        {{BOS:Sequence}}
        <li role="tab" class="{{TabType}}" id="{{tabId}}">
            <span>{{TabFile}}</span>
        </li>
        {{EOS:Sequence}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, I want everything between the {{BOS:Sequece}} and {{EOS:Sequence}}, the tags can be included, I can filter them out.

I've comed up with the following regex:

```
({{BOS:Sequence}})[.]*[\s\S]*({{EOS:Sequence}})
```

This is working correctly, BUT...

However, when my contents change to the following

```
<!-- Defines the template for the tabs. -->
<div class="tabs">
    <ul role="tablist">
        {{BOS:Sequence}}
        <li role="tab" class="{{TabType}}" id="{{tabId}}">
            <span>{{TabFile}}</span>
        </li>
        {{EOS:Sequence}}
    </ul>
</div>

    {{BOS:Sequence}}
    <li role="tab" class="{{TabType}}" id="{{tabId}}">
        <span>{{TabFile}}</span>
    </li>
    {{EOS:Sequence}}
```

Then the regex would match:

```
    {{BOS:Sequence}}
    <li role="tab" class="{{TabType}}" id="{{tabId}}">
        <span>{{TabFile}}</span>
    </li>
    {{EOS:Sequence}}
</ul>
</div>

    {{BOS:Sequence}}
    <li role="tab" class="{{TabType}}" id="{{tabId}}">
        <span>{{TabFile}}</span>
    </li>
    {{EOS:Sequence}}
```

Any idea on how to solve this particular issue?

P.S: I'm writing javascript regex.

Comment: If you use the ungreedy modifier (U) it won't match the inbetween parts of the outer tags, then use global modifier (g) to match all: http://regex101.com/r/cO3oB8/1

Comment: Try this: `/({{BOS:Sequence}})[.]*?[\s\S]*?({{EOS:Sequence}})/g`. `?` is a non greedy modifier. http://regex101.com/r/rF4dV3/1

Answer (score 2):

Your regex should be:

```
{{BOS:Sequence}}[\s\S]*?{{EOS:Sequence}}
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eK7uJ3/1)

Comment: For clarification as to why, is that the question mark `?` makes the expression lazy so it stops at the first chance it can.  where as the star `*` is naturally greedy.  I was going to get fancy with lookarounds like this `(?<={{BOS:Sequence}})[\s\S]*?(?={{EOS:Sequence}})` but it's not necessary, but still fun to learn about regex